# Difference between -filter:retweet and -filter:nativeretweets in Twitter Search API 1.1

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to run some queries against the Twitter API to collect some tweets. I want to filter out retweets and after some research discovered there seems to be two different tags you can append to the search query to filter them `-filter:retweet` and `-filter:nativeretweets`.

I've ran sample queries with both options and can seem to tell the difference. List is returned tweets is slightly different but in no real way I can discern. Neither seem to contain retweets. I won't post the output here as it's a fairly length JSON output but I can if need be.

The sample queries are

**-filter:retweet**

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%22Sample+Query%22-filter:retweet&count=100&include_entities=false&result_type=recent&tweet_mode=extended
```

**-filter:nativeretweets**

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%22Sample+Query%22-filter:nativeretweets&count=100&include_entities=false&result_type=recent&tweet_mode=extended
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe per TweetDeck documentation (https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170322) this is the difference:

`filter:nativeretweets` shows retweets from users who have hit the retweet button.
`filter:retweets` shows old style retweets ("RT") + quoted tweets.

Those are filtering FOR those types of results, but as you've done, the - is necessary to filter them out `-filter:nativeretweets` or `-filter:retweets`

Comment: Experiments would suggest that is the case. However I had spotty results making it work with the negative modifier. It would still seem to include random tweets that had been retweeted but I never figured out a pattern.

Comment: That's interesting. I've been contributing to a bot that retweets based on a keyword and uses these filters and I haven't seen false positives.

However, I'm curious if the web search is different than hitting the API. Is it possible the web search is more generous, and gives you "related" tweets that don't exactly match the filter, if it runs out of "direct match" results to display? 

Of course, keep in mind that all retweets come from an original tweet. Can you tell that it's specifically pulling a retweet of a tweet, and not the original?

Quoted tweets may also be separate.